# How to fix Solr with write.lock?

Tags: solr

I'm trying to load a core, but i have this error:

```
Error CREATEing SolrCore 'core': Unable to create core [core]
Caused by: /path/to/core/data/index/write.lock.
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Lock held elsewhere:
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held elsewhere 
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:
```

I'm unable to load this core in solr 5.5.2

There isn't a write.lock file in the directory specified. I tried to create one, but its useless.

Comment: What is the complete error message? Is the error that it detects a write lock, or that it isn't able to create the lock file? Are there multiple Solr instances being started that uses the same data directory? is the data directory local to the server or stored on a nfs/smb share?

Comment: that is the error message and detects an inexistent write.lock
The error contains:
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Unable to create core
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Lock held elsewhere:
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Lock held elsewhere
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException:

Comment: The error message tells you that the Solr process is denied access to the write.lock file. This may be because of access rights to the core directory (i.e. it's unable to create the lock file). `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException` or that the directory it's attempting to create the lock in doesn't exist. Remember that Solr might be running under a different user account that what you're using yourself.

Comment: When people ask for additional information, please try to edit it into the question (like I did for you).  You want a person to be able to understand your question in its entirety without having to read comments.

Comment: "but its useless" isn't informative.  Were you able to create the lock file?  Did doing so change the error message at all?

Comment: @ConspicuousCompiler Sorry, i'm new here.I'll do.

Comment: Are you able to create a brand new core in that Solr?